# jQuery how to get keyup event capital and small letter value

Tags: jquery, keyboard-events

```
$("#inputField").keyup(function(event) {
  alert(event.keyCode);
  alert(event.charCode);
  alert(event.which);
  alert(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
});
```

- If I press <kbd>A</kbd> (lowercase "a"), output will be: `65, 0, 65, A`
- If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, the output still same: `65, 0, 65, A`

Can someone teach me how to get small letter `a` when I key in `a` and get capital letter `A` when I key in `A`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `keypress` event instead:

```
$("#inputField").keypress(function(e) {
    alert(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
});​
```

**P.S.:** Following [`keyup`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) documentation:

> For catching actual text entry, .keypress() may be a better choice.

Comment: Only with hacking the `shift` key, but the solution might not work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#inputField").keyup(function(event) {
    var code = event.which;
    if(code >= 65 && code <= 90) {
        alert( String.fromCharCode( event.which + 32 ) );
    }
});
```

***[The working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/mvYkU/7/)***

Comment: @xin_yao this will always give you lower case letters

Comment: thanks for the answer but this is not what I want, I want when I type in 'a', it show 'a', type in 'A' then show 'A', but I try your code, no matter I key in 'a' or 'A', it show 'a' to me :(